# Get objects of certain types

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, inheritance, types

I am trying to get Host objects which have `E` objects of certain type like this:

```
return Session.Query<Host>().Where(x => x.E is B).ToList();
```

This does not seem to work probably because E is of type A and B inherits from A. Could the inheritance be the problem. Some more (simplified) details:

```
class Host
{
    public A E { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{

}
```

Any ideas why the above does not work? Thanks.

PS:

**Please note that the above should work - I used the wrong class name!**

Comment: When you say "This does not seem to work", are you saying your returned list contains `Host`s with `E`s that are *not* `B`s ?

Comment: I know that the database contains 2 Host objects and one Host object that has a E object an object of Type B. The above Linq query return 0 elements.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but if you retrieve both objects from the database, _is_ the `.E` a `B`? Maybe the database isn't managing to restore this information.

Comment: Yes I verified this. This is actually part of an integration test. Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn is it NHibernate?

Comment: Is this a Nibernate query ? If so, what version of NH ("is" wont work in NH2 ) ?

Comment: can you try Where(x => (x.E as B) != null)

Comment: Yes I use NH. It is runtime version v2.0.50727 but version (?) 3.3.1.4000 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Session.Query<Host>().Where(x => x.E.GetType().Equals(typeof(B)).ToList();
```

This code works in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Host { E = new B() };

    Console.Write(x.E.GetType().Equals(typeof(B)));
}

class A { }
class B : A { }
class Host { public A E { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Posted my LinqPad-Test... if this isn't working in your project, please consider the completeness of your question

Comment: Ok you are missing a bracket ... will check now.

Comment: @csetzkorn : I would be interested in the generated query if you have it. I am wondering if the generated query will retrieve the whole host table and do an in memory filtering (Might not be an issue depending on the host table size) +1 for Jan P. anyway